# Question on the form of Limit Ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Prove or disprove: Every limit ordinal has the form α+ω
for some ordinal α.

I needed help completing this proof and to see if I was on the right track. My idea was to use induction on α. Suppose β=α+ω for some ordinal α and let $$A=(β_1,β_2,…)$$ the set of all limit ordinals.

Base case: Suppose $β=ω$, then for all nϵω  will do since $$β=ω=n+ω$$

Induction hypothesis: Assume that $$β_i=α_i+ω$$

for all $i<n$.

This is where i get stuck, im not sure if i complete this using induction. But if anyone can offer suggestion that would help a lot. Thanks

Comment: $\omega^2$ and $\omega_1$ are limit ordinals. Are they of the form $\alpha+\omega?$

Comment: well for α=ω+ω+... i thought they were. Or is that not correct?

Comment: ;Is **what** not correct? When you wrote "$\alpha=\omega+\omega+\cdots$ **how many** $\omega$s is that supposed to be?

Comment: Very clever approach! Although it is possible to define infinitary operations on the ordinals and make sense of expressions like $\omega+\omega+\dots$, it appears as though they only want you to consider binary pairings of ordinals under recursive addition here -- no expressions like $\omega+\omega+\dots$ allowed unless explicitly defined.

Comment: If $\omega+\omega+\cdots$ means a simple infinite sequence of $\omega$'s, that is, $\omega\ \omega$'s, then you're saying that $$\alpha=\omega+\omega+\cdots=\omega\cdot\omega=\omega^2.$$ If $\alpha=\omega^2,$ then $\omega+\alpha=\omega^2,$ but $\alpha+\omega\gt\omega^2.$

Comment: @bof Actually, $\omega+\alpha=\omega^2<\omega^2+\omega=\alpha+\omega$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Claim.* Every limit ordinal $\alpha$ is of the form 
$$
\alpha = \omega \cdot \beta
$$
for some unique ordinal $\beta > 0$. Furthermore $\alpha$ can be written as
$$
\alpha = \gamma + \omega
$$
if and only if $\beta$, as above, is a successor ordinal.

It's easy to prove this claim via induction on $\alpha$. The case that $\alpha$ is a limit of limit ordinals is trivial. Otherwise there is some largest limit ordinal $\bar{\alpha} < \alpha$ to which you can apply the induction hypothesis. (Note that $\bar{\alpha} + \omega = \alpha$.)

Comment: While I agree with you here, there are some people who take $0$ to be a limit ordinal, thus eliminating the need to require $\beta>0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila True. I'm actually among those people. But, given that $0$ would give a trivial counterexample to OP's question, I thought in this context $0$ probably shouldn't count as a limit ordinal.

Comment: In other words, for once you were right... :P

Comment: So does that mean $\omega^2$ cant be written as $\gamma+\omega$ for some ordinal $\gamma$ since this only works if $\beta=\omega$ where $\omega$ is not a successor?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Sorry to go so far back in time but I was asking myself a similar question and stumbled across this question. What do you mean by "a limit of limit ordinals"?